# typescript router props object

Tags: typescript, vue.js, router

I get this error when I assign an object defined as an interface with typescript to the properties of the route:
`Type 'Affretement' is not assignable to type 'RouteParamValueRaw | RouteParamValueRaw[]'.`

```
import { Affretement } from 'src/store/affretement/state'
...
props: {
    affretement: {
      type: Object as () => Affretement,
      required: true
    }
  },
...
void $router.push({ name: 'affretementDetails', params: { affretement: props.affretement } })
```

Comment: are you using vue 2 or 3?

Comment: I am using VueJS 3

Comment: please share the whole code$

Comment: Sorry I think we can't pass an object as a parameter because it's an url, you need a base type like a string or a number